# Issue With Will Paginate and Index Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller for the index action, I have;

```
def index
  @documents = current_user.documents.all if current_user
end
```

Anything I add on the end of current_user I get an error. For example, I tried to add will_paginate which is simply adding `.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])` to the end of the index action and adding `<%= will_paginate @documents %>` to the views.

Once I add the `.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])` to the end of the index method, like this;

```
def index
  @documents = current_user.documents.all if current_user.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
end
```

I get a `NoMethodError`. Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def index
  @documents = current_user.documents.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) if current_user
end
```

Comment: .paginate works only on ActiveRecord::Relation, and .all converts relation to array

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method on the wrong object, here is the correct one:

```
@documents = current_user.documents.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) if current_user
```

Comment: Now the error I've got is `undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007fe41aa7dba8>`

Comment: I guess I answered from a Mongoid background after all :).